# ¿Cómo separo los números pares de una Matriz de numeros aleatorios usando Math.random

Tags: java, matrices, netbeans-8.2, matriz

**Estoy creando un programa que genera aleatoriamente números en una matriz de NXN. Lo genera y lo muestra correctamente, pero tengo problemas para separar los números pares y también necesito promediar todos los números pares que encuentro. Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora:
No se si lo estoy haciendo bien o no la verdad **

```
package test;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Test {

    static int matriz[][];
    static int filas;
    static int columnas;
    static double promedio;
    static int acumulador;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        matrizr();

    }

    public static void matrizr() {

        filas = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la cantidad de filas que desea "));
        columnas = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la cantidad de columnas que desea"));

        matriz = new int[filas][columnas];

        for (int i = 0; i < filas; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columnas; j++) {

                matriz[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 21);

                if (matriz[i][j] % 2 == 0) {
                    
                    acumulador = acumulador + matriz[i][j];

                }
                promedio = acumulador / matriz[i][j];
            }
        }
  
        mostrarDatos();
    }

    public static void mostrarDatos(){
        
         String mensaje = "";
        
        for (int i = 0; i < filas; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columnas; j++) {
                
               
                mensaje = mensaje + matriz[i][j] + "  ";
             //   promedio = acumulador / Matriz[i][j] ;   
                  
            }
            
            mensaje = mensaje + "\n";
        }
        
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, mensaje);
        
       
         
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El promedio de numeros de la matriz es de " + promedio);
        
    }
    
        
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo  que te hace falta es conocer el total de números pares que se generaron en tu matriz . si tu variable acumulador se encarga de sumar todos los numeros pares ,puedes hacer uso de esa misma condicional if para obtener el total de numeros pares existentes haciendo uso de una variable acumulativa

```
static double acumulador;
static int contador;

public static void matrizr() {

    filas = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la cantidad de filas que desea "));
    columnas = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la cantidad de columnas que desea"));

        matriz = new int[filas][columnas];
    
        for (int i = 0; i < filas; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columnas; j++) {
    
                matriz[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 21);
                if (matriz[i][j] % 2 == 0) {
                    
                    acumulador = acumulador + matriz[i][j];
                    contador++;//aumentara en 1 al encontrar un numero par
    
                }    
            }
        }
    
        promedio = acumulador / contador;
    
        mostrarDatos();
    }

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El promedio de numeros de la matriz es de " + Math.round(promedio*100.0)/100d);
```